Why are test functions always taken to be Schwartz in quantum field theory?
A quantum field theory is defined as a measure over tempered distributions. Why do we take the space of test functions to always be Schwartz space? Why don't we, for example, smear fields using $C^\infty_c$ functions and so the theory is defined as a measure over $\mathcal{D}'$? I suspect this has to do with $\mathcal{D}'$ being a larger and less well-behaved space than $\mathcal{S}'$ and so it is more difficult space to define a probability measure on it. Is there any other reason?

Because Fourier analysis exists only over $\mathcal{S}'$. This gives us access to momentum space arguments, which are extremely useful both in mathematical and physical approaches to quantum field theory. However the constraint is essentially technical. There are known extensions to non-tempered distributions. One such extension is due to Arthur Jaffe and the resulting field theories are known as Jaffe fields. The original paper is 'High-Energy Behavior in Quantum Field Theory. I. Strictly Localizable Fields'.
There is an article due to Franco Strocchi arguing that fermion fields in the coulomb gauge in $U(1)$ gauge theory are probably Jaffe fields, rather than conventional tempered fields. The 'gauge transformation' fields $:\exp(iq\chi):$ must also be Jaffe fields.
Addendum: To elaborate on the point about fourier analysis on $S'$, they key point is that $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{S}'$ is dense. Furthermore, $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{S}\to \mathcal{S}$ is a continuous linear operator. Thus, it can be extended to act on its dual space thanks to this continuity and extending from this dense set. As ACuriousMind mentioned in the comments, the Fourier transform does not preserve $C_c^\infty$ so one cannot hope to repeat such an argument for $\mathcal{D}'$.

Did you mean this paper by Strocchi:  https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.162.1429 ?

@Buzz Not quite that one. The paper I had in mind was 'Proof of the charge superselection rule in local relativistic quantum field theory' which I have linked above.

Indeed, this choice cannot have physical meaning. Every result where it is crucial to smear the fields with Schwartz functions  should be considered very suspicious from a physical point of view.
In general curved spacetime the Schwartz space cannot have any relevance as it is related to a special choice of spacetime coordinates. Coordinates related to the isometries of the spacetime. In the absence of maximal isometries (as it happens in our spacetime as soon as one switches on garavity), the only reasonable space is the one of smooth compactly supported functions.
In fact, there is a reformulation of constructive QFT (in Minkowski spacetime) based only on smooth compactly supported smearing functions. I am referring to a well known book by H. Araki.
I understand that just for historical reasons, and also for practical mathematical reasons (a nice use of Fourier transform), the use of the Schwartz space was prominent.

Thank you. This is a very interesting point that I had never thought of, and my question seems to have more physical meaning than I originally anticipated.
